# Sending SMS using HTML Form with PHP & External SMS API

Tags: php, sms

I am trying to send SMS notification directly from my admin panel to my students mobile number. For this I have written a html form like:

```
<form action="" method="post" >                 

<input type="hidden" name="userName" value="01737********"/>
<input type="hidden" name="userPassword" value="********"/>
<input type="hidden" name="maskName" value="UTSHO LAB" />
<input type="hidden" name="campaignName" value="Admin Panel"/>

<input type="text" name="mobileNumber" />
<textarea name="smsText"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send SMS"/>

</form>
```

And I am trying the below PHP Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST[submit])) 

{

$userName = $_POST['userName'];
$userPassword = $_POST['userPassword'];
$mobileNumber = $_POST['mobileNumber'];
$smsText = $_POST['smsText'];
$maskName = $_POST['maskName'];
$campaignName = $_POST['campaignName'];

try{
        $soapClient = new SoapClient("https://api2.onnorokomsms.com/sendsms.asmx?wsdl");
        $paramArray = array(
        'userName'=>"$userName",
        'userPassword'=>"$userPassword",
        'mobileNumber'=> "$mobileNumber",
        'smsText'=>"$smsText",
        'type'=>"TEXT",
        'maskName'=> "$maskName",
        'campaignName'=>"$campaignName",
        );
        $value = $soapClient->__call("OneToOne", array($paramArray));
        } catch (dmException $e) {

        echo $msg = "<button class='button primary'>$e</button>";
}

}

?>
```

But this code doesn't worked at all. Please help me to find my mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't worked at all"? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: The above code is not returning any error - $msg at all. Just no message is sent!

Comment: First check your php configuration, make sure SOAP extension is enabled.

Comment: Also UTSHO LAB mask name will not work if it is not verified. For that you can try removing mask name. And without knowing error message it is hard to provide any solve.

Comment: Thanks, @Masum , Yes, I have tried by removing mask name. But nothing happened. Can you say how do I get error messages from above code? You may suggest me a correction as well.